# Civibuild issues?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

Has anyone tried running `civibuild` recently to create a CiviCRM environment under Drupal 9?  I have been running it on a Ubuntu 20.4 virtual machine and hit various issues. To build `drupal9-clean` I had to copy `composer` from a running Drupal 9 instance to `buildkit/build/drupal9-clean/vendor` as it was not installed by `civibuild`.

Comment: About 2 months ago I did it for something and it seemed ok. The d9-master.demo.civicrm.org site is built daily using it. I remember there being some issues with composer v2 - not sure if that's been settled. Which version of composer do you have?

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't composer that was broken, but the composer directory tree.  I've just built drupal9-demo, but it needed two passes.  Civibuild just seems a bit fragile.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: As of 8-26-2021 the below command works just fine with current buildkit, it's just not in the civibuild docs yet afaik:**

```
civibuild create d9dev --type drupal9-clean --civi-ver master --url http://d9.localhost
```

As of today (4-21-2021 env Ubuntu 20.04), I used the command

```
civibuild create d9dev --type drupal9-clean --civi-ver master --url http://d9.localhost
```

Which ran into errors because it couldn't find a valid civicrm root (/vendor did not include a civicrm directory at this time). I needed to run the command, then manually:

```
composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer require civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:'~1.1'
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.35'
```

Then I ran the same civibuild command again to finish out the build process and get the .sh file with login info etc. I ended up with a working copy of Drupal 9 version 9.0.12-dev and CiviCRM 5.36.0.

Hope that's helpful!